# How to return a String of all linked list Integers in reverse order?

Tags: java, string, debugging, linked-list, reverse

Initial curr_node is assumed to always be head.  Implementation of LLNode follows implementation of this code snippet. How do I make it work?

```
private String toString(LLNode<Integer> curr_node) {
    // TODO
    if(curr_node==null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return curr_node.data+toString(curr_node.link);
    }
}

public class LLNode<T> {
    public T data;
    public LLNode<T> link;
    public LLNode() {
        this(null, null);
    }
    public LLNode(T data, LLNode<T> link) {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:

```
private String toString(LLNode<Integer> curr_node) {
    if(curr_node==null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return toString(curr_node.link) + "," + curr_node.data; // Your code is the reverse
    }
}
```